# moving multiple files under while loop using wxwidget

Tags: c++, wxwidgets

I have been writing a c++ code for myself,which iterates in a directory and will move files in to a directory of the same name as the file

```
   \\\\
           void foldersFrame::OnButton2Click(wxCommandEvent& event)
            {
                wxFileName mkr;
                StaticText1->SetLabel(_("0"));
                wxString fn;
                wxString newf;
                wxDir *dir=new wxDir(TextCtrl1->GetLabel());
                bool cont = dir->GetFirst(&fn);
                while (cont)
                {
                    int mm=fn.Find('.',true);
                    newf=fn.Mid(0,mm);
                    if(! mkr.DirExists(dir->GetName()+_("\\")+fn)){
                        StaticText2->SetLabel(_("copying  ")+fn);
                        if (! mkr.DirExists(dir->GetName()+_("\\")+newf)){
                            mkr.Mkdir(dir->GetName()+_("\\")+newf);
                            if (wxCopyFile(dir->GetName()+_("\\")+fn,dir->GetName()+_("\\")+newf+_("\\")+fn)){
                                wxRemoveFile(dir->GetName()+_("\\")+fn);
                            }
                            newf=StaticText1->GetLabel();
                            long d1;
                            if(!newf.ToLong(&d1));
                            d1+=1;
                            StaticText1->SetLabel(wxString::Format(wxT("%i"),d1));
                        }
                    }
                    cont = dir->GetNext(&fn);
                }
                wxSafeShowMessage(_("Message"),_("Finished"));
            }
```

But the code i have written seem to be very inefficient.It takes a lot of time to move files,and the window doesn't respond while copying.Someone please help me rewrite it..!!!!

Comment: If you want a responsive user interface while doing intensive or long-running operations you should put those in a thread.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have two standard ways to implement a long running task.

First one, and by far the best, is to perform this task in a separate background thread. You can update the state of the GUI controls in the main thread by posting `wxThreadEvent` containing the progress data to the main window easily. The only complication -- but a pretty important one -- in this case is to handle closing the window/application termination/thread exit correctly.

Second one, which could do in a pinch, is to do the task in `wxEVT_IDLE` handler piece by piece and call `wxIdleEvent::RequestMore()` after each step. This is not as responsive as using a separate thread because you still block the event handling during the handler execution and the code needs to be rewritten in a different way to be able to resume from where it left off.

Using `wxYield()` is a pretty bad idea and should be avoided unless no other solution can be implemented.

Answer (score 2):

To keep the application window responsive, but without going to the extra trouble of doing the file copy in a separate thread, try using Yield.  Needs care!

wxApp::Yield

bool Yield(bool onlyIfNeeded = false)

Yields control to pending messages in the windowing system. This can be useful, for example, when a time-consuming process writes to a text window. Without an occasional yield, the text window will not be updated properly, and on systems with cooperative multitasking, such as Windows 3.1 other processes will not respond.

Caution should be exercised, however, since yielding may allow the user to perform actions which are not compatible with the current task. Disabling menu items or whole menus during processing can avoid unwanted reentrance of code: see ::wxSafeYield for a better function.

Note that Yield() will not flush the message logs. This is intentional as calling Yield() is usually done to quickly update the screen and popping up a message box dialog may be undesirable. If you do wish to flush the log messages immediately (otherwise it will be done during the next idle loop iteration), call wxLog::FlushActive.

Calling Yield() recursively is normally an error and an assert failure is raised in debug build if such situation is detected. However if the onlyIfNeeded parameter is true, the method will just silently return false instead.